# Seg fault calling Cygwin from C#

Tags: c#, c++, cygwin

I have some C++ code originally written for Linux that I can build and run without problems under 64-bit Windows using gcc under cygwin. Now, however, I want to turn it into a DLL that I can invoke from a C# program.

I find I can get C# to call C++ functions compiled under cygwin without problems, as long as they don't use any of the standard C/C++ library functions defined in cygwin1.dll. But as soon as I do a printf, for example, the whole thing exits with a "Segmentation fault".

Searching for answers online, I see it claimed that you need to call cygwin_dll_init() first. However, when I add that, it simply terminates with no error message at all!

What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty sure that the .NET runtime is successfully finding both my DLL and cygwin1.dll, because I get a DllNotFoundException instead if either isn't present.

Here's a minimal test case that produces the same symptoms. First, the cygwin/C++ code for the DLL:

```
#include <cstdio>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int test();

int test() {
    printf("Test successful");
    return 14;
}
```

I compile this with "g++ -o test.dll -shared test.cpp".

Here's the C# code that invokes it:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class MainClass {
    [DllImport("cygwin1.dll")]
    private static extern void cygwin_dll_init();
    
    [DllImport("test.dll")]
    private static extern int test();
    
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("running...");

        // Remove this line if you want a seg fault
        cygwin_dll_init();

        test();

        // Seg fault or no, this never gets run
        Console.WriteLine("done");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the command(s) (or the command(s) from makefile) that you use to compile and link your program.

Comment: As stated above, the DLL is compiled with "g++ -o test.dll -shared test.cpp". The C# code is compiled with "csc.exe -t:exe -out:test.exe test2.cs -nologo".

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend that you compile your DLL using the mingw64 cross compiler. This allows you to build an DLLs that does not use the cygwin1.dll. Instead, it will call the Windows runtime DLLs only. As long as you do not need to call any other cygwin DLLs, this should work fine.

1. you will need to install the mingw64 compiler package using the cygwin setup app. Install the `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++` package.
2. create GNUmakefile as follows:

```
 # GNUmakefile - for cygwin make will use this instead of Makefile

CXX=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror

all:    libtest.dll

clean:
    rm -f *.dll

libtest.dll:  test.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -shared -o libtest.dll test.cpp
```

3. At a cygwin bash prompt, run `make clean all`
4. Create Makefile as follows:

```
# Makefile - for VS nmake

CS=csc
CSFLAGS=-nologo -w:3 -warnaserror+ -optimize- -debug+

all :   main.exe

clean :
    del /q *.exe 2> nul:
    del /q *.pdb 2> nul:

main.exe : main.cs
    $(CS) $(CSFLAGS) -t:exe -out:main.exe main.cs
```

5. Run this at a cmd.exe prompt as `nmake -nologo clean all`.
6. Run the exe as `main.exe`. As usual libtest.dll must be in the same directory as main.exe, or in the path.

The makefiles here are cut down from versions that build with and without using the cygwin1.dll and, I hope don't, but may contain errors.

Comment: I should have mentioned that you should edit your main.cs to remove line 5-6 and 14-15.